# How to send a form from a file index.html to a file success.html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

please tell me if there is a problem with sending the name and phone number form. There is an **index.html** file in which there are fields for entering the name and phone number, there is also a file **send.php** which sends the data to my email, after clicking the "Place an order" button on the **index.html** page, it transfers to **send.php** , and **send.php** it 's already on the page **success.html** . I would like to make it so that on the page **succes.html** the data of the name and phone number entered on the page were displayed **index.html** to verify the correctness of the entered data by customers, while not losing the ability to receive notifications about requests by mail that the file sends **send.php**

And how to make the name and phone data appear in a certain place in the file **success.html**

I tried to do it through jQuery:

```
/*! FormChimp v1.2.1 | Fabio Quarantini - http://www.fabioquarantini.com */ 
! function(a, b, c, d) {
  a.fn.formchimp = function(b) {
    var d = a(this),
      e = a("body"),
      f = d.attr("action").replace("/post?", "/post-json?").concat("&c=?"),
      g = d.find('[type="submit"]'),
      h = {
        appendElement: d,
        buttonSelector: g,
        buttonText: "",
        debug: !1,
        errorMessage: "",
        onMailChimpSuccess: function() {},
        onMailChimpError: function() {},
        responseClass: "mc-response",
        successMessage: "",
        url: f
      },
      i = h.buttonSelector.text();
    a.extend(h, b), a(d).on("submit", function(b) {
      b.preventDefault(), e.removeClass("mc-success mc-error").addClass("mc-loading"), 0 === a("." + h.responseClass).length ? $responseContainer = a("<div/>").addClass(h.responseClass).appendTo(h.appendElement) : $responseContainer.html(""), a.ajax({
        url: h.url,
        data: d.serialize(),
        dataType: "jsonp"
      }).done(function(b) {
        h.debug && console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
        var d = b.msg;
        isNaN(d.charAt(0)) || "-" !== d.charAt(2) || (d = d.substring(3)), e.addClass("mc-" + b.result).removeClass("mc-loading"), "success" === b.result ? ("" !== h.successMessage && (d = h.successMessage), "" !== h.buttonText && h.buttonSelector.text(h.buttonText), a(c).trigger("mailChimpSuccess"), h.onMailChimpSuccess.call()) : ("" !== h.errorMessage && (d = h.errorMessage), "" !== h.buttonText && h.buttonSelector.text(i), a(c).trigger("mailChimpError"), h.onMailChimpError.call()), $responseContainer.html(d)
      })
    })
  }
}(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Don't post minified code, no one can reasonably be expected to read and understand it.

Comment: You can put the values in cookies or URL query parameters. Then the JavaScript on `success.html` can get these values and display them in the DOM.

Comment: Barmar, Or can you explain a little more like this, I'm new to this business

Comment: Redirect to `success.html?name=Joe&number=123-456-7890`. Then the JS on `success.html` can extract the name and number from `window.location.search` and display them.